# How Would A Society of PCs Deal With Overpowered Individuals?

Tags: society, magic, social-norms

Background: Through use of a reality-altering force, people were brought into a fantasy-style MMORPG (as PCs) on a whole new continent made just for them and formed a society. These people all hold Classes (like Dnd or Final Fantasy) and level up from 1 to 500, becoming stronger over time.

For an idea of how that works, a Lvl. 1 Ranger or Ninja is an unusually skilled, slightly enhanced human being. A Level 500 Ranger or Ninja, however, is the very best of their respective Class, their abilities enhanced to supernatural levels. For example, a Lvl. 500 Ninja can strike faster than the human eye can track, become invisible in shadows, and is so fast and precise that an ordinary (or low-level) target has almost no chance of surviving their attack.

The scale is simple: a Lvl. 2 Ninja is 1/2 more enhanced and capable than a Lvl. 1 Ninja.

However, my question is about the Lvl. 500 people. Let's say six people found a glitch that allows them to become Lvl. 625 instead of 500. The difference between Lvl. 625 and 500 is *huge*; these individuals have powers that are *godlike*
(in sheer power and scope) within their respective Classes. This disparity becomes even greater because in this game, PCs have two Classes while only 5% of NPCs have two classes (and those people are always exceptional in some way).

These PCs are:

1. Warrior/Barbarian
2. Sage (Scientific spellcaster)/Engineer
3. Commando/Ninja
4. Hunter/Ranger
5. Diplomat/Healer
6. Paladin/Monk

So, how would a society of PCs, American in origin, employ six people with such incredible power?

Comment: Thank you, is it better now?

Comment: A question of type "How would X react to..." is generally off-topic as too much opinion-based. On the other hand, questions like "How X can be able to control ..." may be on topic.

Comment: Okay, I will consider that, thank you!

Comment: Your title and second-to-last sentence are vague, as "react" and "deal" leave a lot of room for interpretation. Do they "react" on a societal level, or mob-based, or quasi-individually (eg, small groups or solo)? Are they trying to "deal" with these people as in lock them up, murder them, bind their souls for personal use, trade, barter, etc?  More generally, what do the "godlike" powers of level 625 players affect: scale, range, power, scope? Finally, thematic abilities are vague - does "infuse shots with Nature magic" mean their arrows trigger tsunamis / earthquakes, or plant-based effects?

Comment: 1/2. First please understand that all suggestions and even VTC are, hopefully, geared towards making your question valid so you can get a valid ANSWER. If I have to guess what you what then you won't get a good answer. Then you have a lot of problems in the question. The amount of information is unneeded and redundant. Cut all those classes and stuff and focus on important information. Give a single example if you want so you still convey the information but not clutter the question. Second clearly define what you what in the first place. People reacting is a HUGE subject. Focus on a certain

Comment: 2/2. Aspect that you want solved. Because this is opinion based you need to focus it. example how can lv 500 people defeat lv 600 in battle or. Or how can the average people create a social structure to benefit both parties and create a peaceful coexistence between the 2 groups...etc.
Lastly I think you have a solid problem in that the higher levels are better. In reality if Lvl. 2 = 1/2 more than a Lvl. 1. Then this is already a major problem. Also the first person to get to 500 would be that to others and would deny leveling up to lower levels. lv 500 have the same issues, just scaled down.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've changed the question to 'how would this society employ people with such power?"

Comment: would they die permanently if they are killed? or do they use health point/bar? do they require magic point/bar to do activity or can they get tired? also what do you mean with "how would a society of PCs, American in origin, employ six people with such incredible power?" are your objective is to bring down this overpower individuals? with certain strategy or tactic and group coordination and how to utilize their technique/skill better ppl can bring down overpower person, basically git gud. or is this mean for living harmoniously? or to utilize them to their maximum potential for society?

Comment: Quick history primer: remember Hannibal Barca. In the context of this question, he was a level 625 Strategist class. He was *so much better* than the Romans that Hannibal dealt *several* of the greatest defeats of the Roman empire in history. Which is all to say, we can consider him "overpowered". Yet, the Roman empire won the war thanks to [the Fabian strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabian_strategy). Named after the leader who employed it. Basically, it means avoid engagement and battle the enemy through attrition. The strategy has since been in use through the ages. Perfect fit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What do people need to do in their society?**

Most people are OK with not doing battle on a day to day basis.  Most people want to live their lives battle free as much as possible.  For example - despite my ability to summon a hail of flaming brussels sprouts from the sky, I find little need for that in my day to day life.  On my commute there are usually not obstacles warranting the hail of flaming sprouts.  My coworkers are well behaved.  The police and fire department handle troubles out in the city.  I earn my pay, eat my food, pet my cat and do not summon the sprouts of flame.  I am ok with that!

The question for your supers and your world in general: what need do they have for their powers?  And what else do they have to do? You say a lot about the powers of these people but you do not lay out the day to day existence in this world.   For example - do they need jobs to earn money to pay rent and buy food?

I could imagine that if this were a game with monsters that had to be fought, but most people in the world were content to work their farms and raise their kids and go to church and not battle monsters, they might hire the supers who by virtue of the glitch can easily take care of the perils produced by the game.  Everyone else can live a normal life.  And the supers too can be part of that - they could have a schedule and take time off in between shifts.

There can still be ritualistic dances, I am sure.

Comment: Good point! This is easily one of the best answers I've seen.

Comment: High praise @Alendyias!  How about an upvote?  That is how it works here.